# If /else statement in Twilio Function always return false

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

I want to test my if else condition in the Twilio function.
The condition is if the user will text "Hi", Twilio will send him a quote.
The problem the condition always runs false even if I texted "Hi".
I'm not sure if the `event.Body` is the right code to get the value of the message body.

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
 const got = require('got');
 
 got('https://cyan-sparrow-7490.twil.io/assets/quote.json').then(response =>{
     let messageBody = event.Body;
     
     const qotd = JSON.parse(response.body);
     let quote = qotd.contents.quotes[0];
     const quoteEffect = messageBody === "Hi"? callback(null,quote): callback(null,null);
     callback(null,quoteEffect);
 });
};
```

Comment: Console log `event.Body` and see what you get.

Comment: Hi Alan, the return is null in the console.log, Do you know how to get the value of the event.Body?

Comment: Have you tried `event.body.Body`? I think the `POST` from Twilio is a bit nested, at least that's how I used to get it.

Comment: Is Twiliio Studio involved (Run Function Widget) and are you sending the value of body into the Twilio Function as a Function parameter? https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/run-function

Comment: Yes, yvesonline I already tried that. Still cannot get the value of the body of the message.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I already figure out a different way.

Comment: You can share how you fixed it as an answer so that others can see what you did.

Comment: Okay philnash, I just post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1,

- Use the split Based Widget and input to the "Variable to Test" **trigger.message.Body**
  [image]
- Then add a condition in the Split Based Widget that could be found in the Transitions tab, if the incoming messages is equal to "Hi" then it will proceed to the next widget

[image]

Step 2,

- Then add a message widget that tells the sender Fetching quote, the purpose of this is just to tell the sender that your processing the quoted message. This is just optional, you can remove this if you want.

[image]

Step 3

- Then create a function to parse the external API for the quoted message. Make sure to add the got module as Dependencies
  [image]

[image]

[image]

Step 4

- And Lastly Parsed the Quote in the Body of the Send Message widget.

[image]